# How can I write valid JUnit tests when mocking a filepath?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am trying to write some JUnit tests for a set of methods which use some REST services on the web.

In general, within my methods, I am providing a filepath and a configuration as a parameter, but I expect things will get more complicated as I progress.

For right now, what are the best ways for me to write JUnit tests for the likes of :

```
public Answers changeFileToAnswer(String filePath, String mediaType) {
    File document = new File(filePath);
    Answers answers = restService.changeFileToAnswer(document, mediaType);
    return answers;
}
```

What kind of Unit tests can I write for a simple class like this? Testing the answers object would be an integration tests, since an external call is made here, right? What is good practise here? Is there a way to mock the filepath being passed in as a parameter?

**Notes -** 
This method is from a REST interface which will later be exposed through a GUI. I am currently testing it with POST calls from POSTman. Due to this, I am passing in a string for the filePath rather than a file object (as I could not post this to my server).

Thanks.

Comment: Well, everything would become easier, if you wouldn't do the "new File()" within your method. Why not pass in a file object for example?!

Comment: @GhostCat I was thinking that too! In my class that would result in lots of repetition though, so I think that would be bad practise too? I guess it's a toss-up between brevity and testability?

Comment: Hi Simon, is there a reason why you are using File, as opposed to java.nio.file.Path?

Comment: @LucasT Well, at the moment this is a method which will be invoked by a POST call made to a server. I am testing it with POSTman currently - I don't believe it would work if I used a java.file.Path call? Sorry - I should have mentioned this. Will update now.

Answer (score 2):

The test is not necessary to be integration. Your `restService` need to be  mock or fake, so there is no real external call.
For mocking filePath you can use [JUnit TemporaryFolder](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html).

```
public class TestClass{
    @Rule
    private TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void testMethod(){
        File tempFile = folder.newFile("myfile.txt");
        classUnderTest.changeFileToAnswer(file.getPath(), mediaType);
    }
}
```

This rule will create a real file in file system which will be removed when tests finish execution.

UPD: You might also want to take a look at [jimfs](https://github.com/google/jimfs)